# Django form with __init__ doesn't clean fields

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have a django form I'm attempting to add CAPTCHA support to. However, this requires me to pass request.session to the form. To accomplish that, I added this constructor to the form:

```
def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.request = request
```

I then instantiate the RegistrationForm by passing the request object to it. However, when submitting the form, it fails to clean any of the fields. It just fails validation and passes a blank field back to the template. Here is the registration code that fails:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...do registration...
    else:
        return render(request, 'template.htm', {'form': form})
```

No matter what I put in the fields, it never validates. In fact, it doesn't even look like it cleans the fields. I just get back a new blank form after hitting the register button, no errors, nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the else block, can you put `form.errors` and see what the error is ?

Comment: You need to do some debugging yourself; unless this is a known issue, it won't be easy to answer with the information presented here. Put print statements here and there to see what's going on with your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, it looks as though you are passing `request.POST` into the `request` parameter for your `RegistrationForm`. i.e. you are doing the equivalent of:

```
form = RegistrationForm(request=request.POST)
```

What you really want to do is this:

```
form = RegistrationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
```

Try this and see if it works for you.